# How to open a file chooser so I can choose a file and upload it?

Tags: file-upload, cordova, sencha-touch, file-browser

I'm wroking on file upload on sencha project,I want to tap "Select file" button on sencha's panel to display a file choose dialog box,so I can tap in a folder to select file to upload.I at first used this method:

```
function openFileSelector() {
    var source = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
    var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI; 
    var mediaType = navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA;  
    var options={  
        quality : 50,  
        destinationType : destinationType,  
        sourceType : source,  
        mediaType : mediaType,
        allowEdit : true,    
    };  
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadFile,uploadBroken,options);  
};
function uploadFile(fileURI) {  
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();  
    options.fileKey = "file"; 
    options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    fN = options.fileName;
    document.getElementById("process_file").innerHTML = fN;
    options.mimeType = "multipart/form-data"; 
    options.chunkedMode = false;  
    ft = new FileTransfer();  
    var    uploadUrl=encodeURI(Global.proxyPortAndIP+"/tyoa/page/phone/docbase/docUploadFile.jsp");  
    ft.upload(fileURI,uploadUrl,uploadSuccess, uploadFailed, options);
    ft.onprogress = uploadProcessing;
    $('.upload_process_bar,#process_info,#process_file').show();  
}
```

However,this method has two shortages:
1) It only works well on a few cellphones.That means on some cellphones when I tap "Select file" button,it can give me an option list,so I can choose "file manager" option to select file.But on some other devices it only show folders that contain pictures.
2) It doesn't return a right file path.When alert() the options.fileName it shows something like "content://media/external/images/media/3746",what I want is somewhat like "/mnt/sdcard/..../777.jpg".
Later I tried phonegap's *window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, fail)*,
it can find all directories and files on sdcard,but can't give me a view of that.So I began to realise I may have to build a file browser myself,I refered to http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/9/PhoneGaps-File-API 
http://www.digitalnoiz.com/mobile-development/mobile-file-explorer-with-phonegapcordova-and-jquery-mobile-part-1/ 
and [http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/file-chooser-dialog-for-phonegap-application/] 
for any possible solution,I have to say those are quite good posts,but I encountered some problems in transplanting the methods from index.html into my project.
My "Select file" button is in a sencha js file,all relative methods are in a upload.js file,

```
/**FileTransfer*/  
var ft;  
var fN;  
/** 
 * clear uploading progress,dealing with uploading fail,abort and success 
 */  
function clearProcess() {  
    $('.upload_process_bar,#process_info,#process_file').hide();  
    ft.abort();  
};  

/** 
 * open file selector 
 */  
function openFileSelector() {
alert("file system");
//window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, fail);
//alert("after file system");
var source = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;  
var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI;
alert("destinationType: "+destinationType);  
var mediaType = navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA;  
var options={  
    quality : 50,  
    destinationType : destinationType,  
    sourceType : source,  
    mediaType : mediaType,
    allowEdit : true,    
};  
navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadFile,uploadBroken,options);  
};  

function onFSSuccess(fileSystem){
alert("fileSystem: "+fileSystem);
var directoryReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
directoryReader.readEntries(successReader,fail);
};
function successReader(entries){
var s="";
for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++){

    if(entries[i].isDirectory==true){
        //alert("directory: "+entries[i].fullPath);
        //var directoryReaderIn = entries[i].createReader();
        //directoryReaderIn.readEntries(successReader,fail);
        s += " [D]";
    }
    if(entries[i].isFile==true){
        //alert("file: "+entries[i].name);
        //entries[i].file(uploadFile, fail);
        s += " [F]";
    }
    s+= entries[i].fullPath;
    s += "<br/>";
    //alert(s);
}
s+="<p/>";
logit(s);
};
function fail(e){
alert(e);
};

/** 
 * dealing with uploading broke 
 * @param message 
 */  
function uploadBroken(message){   
clearProcess();  
};  

/** 
 * uploading callback,show the progress 
 */  
function uploadProcessing(progressEvent){  

if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {  
    //already uploaded  
    var loaded=progressEvent.loaded;  
    //file size  
    var total=progressEvent.total;  
    //calculate the percentage
    var percent=parseInt((loaded/total)*100);  
    //换算成MB  
    loaded=(loaded/1024/1024).toFixed(2);  
    total=(total/1024/1024).toFixed(2);  
    $('#process_info').html(loaded+'M/'+total+'M');  
    $('.upload_current_process').css({'width':percent+'%'});  
}  
};  

/** 
 * upload the file
 */  
function uploadFile(fileURI) {  
var options = new FileUploadOptions();  
options.fileKey = "file"; 
options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
fN = options.fileName;
alert(fileURI+"  fileName:"+fN);
document.getElementById("process_file").innerHTML = fN;
options.mimeType = "multipart/form-data"; 
options.chunkedMode = false;  
ft = new FileTransfer();  
var uploadUrl=encodeURI(Global.proxyPortAndIP+"/tyoa/page/phone/docbase/docUploadFile.jsp");  
ft.upload(fileURI,uploadUrl,uploadSuccess, uploadFailed, options);  
//get upload progress
ft.onprogress = uploadProcessing;  
//show the progress bar  
$('.upload_process_bar,#process_info,#process_file').show();  
 }  

/** 
 * callback after successfully uploaded
 * @param
 */  
function uploadSuccess(r) {
if(r.response){
    document.getElementById("process_file").innerHTML = fN;
    alert('Upload success!');  
}else{
    alert('Upload failed!');  
} 
clearProcess();  
}  

/** 
 * callback after upload failed 
 * @param error 
 */  
function uploadFailed(error) {  
alert('Upload failed！');  
clearProcess();  
}  

/** 
 *  
 */  
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){  
$(function(){  
     $('#upload_file_link').click(openFileSelector);  
});  
}, false);
```

where to display the directories and files still a problem for me,I provisional put them in div in the panel

```
Ext.define('tyoa.view.more.docbase.DocAddFile', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: 'widget.docAddFile',
xtype: 'docAddFile',
requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet','Ext.ux.Fileup'],
config: {
    fullscreen:true,    
    layout: {  
      type: 'vbox',          
     },  
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'File Detail',
            items: [
                {
                    ui: 'back',
                    text: 'Cyber Disk',
                    align: 'left',
                    action: 'backDocbaseList',                  
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            html:
            '<h1><button><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="upload_file_link" onclick="openFileSelector();" style="text-decoration:none">Choose a file to upload</a></button></h1>'+
            //'<a href="fileindex.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="browseBtn1">Browse</a>'+ 
            '<div id="process_file"></div> '+   
            '<div class="upload_process_bar">'+   
            '<div class="upload_current_process"></div>'+   
            '</div>'+  
            '<div id="process_info"></div>'+

            '<div id="content"></div>'
             //'<div data-role="content">'+
                //'<b><span id="curr_folder"></span></b><br/>'+
                //'<a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="new_file_btn" data-theme="b" class="small_btn">New File</a>'+
                //'<a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="new_dir_btn" data-theme="b" class="small_btn">New Dir</a>'+

                //'<div id="fileBrowser_entries"></div>'+

                //'<a href="#" id="file_browser_ok" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" id="file_browser_ok">OK</a>'+       
                //'<a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" id="file_browser_cancel">Cancel</a>'+       
            //'</div>'+
            //'<span id="fileMsgSpan"></span>'
        },
    ]
}
});
```

Of course it's not a good place but I have no good idea yet.Although I successfully displayed the sdcard content still can't tap in any folder,let alone select file.I just find it's hard to disintergate those methods,seperated methods are usually out of function.
If anyone has any suggestion,I'm all ears.Any help will be apprecited!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sencha extension for uploading file:
https://market.sencha.com/extensions/file-uploading-component-for-sencha-touch
You can see demo here: http://mindsaur.com/demo/fileupload/

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but I think this is exectly the one I used before,it can't work on mobile phone.I'm using st 2.0,however,I think the reason is this component can't find a phone's sdcard directory.